# ant war plugin trying to exclude folders

Tags: maven, ant, war, maven-antrun-plugin

Hi I am using ant war plugin and trying to exclude a folder from teh war. however this is not being excluded.

Here is the structure

```
   XYZ
      src
         main
             webapp
                   web-inf
                         web.xml
                   common
                         api
                            a.js
                            b.js
```

My build.xml for target = production looks like this, i am try to exclude teh common folder. However I see that it is not excluding it at all

```
<target name="production" depends="moveresources"
        description="Building the Production Directory Content">
    <echo message="Creating -> ${workingDirectory}"/>
    <war destfile="${workingDirectory}/horizonadmin.war" webxml="${srcDirectory}/WEB-INF/web.xml">
        <fileset dir="${webappsrc}"/>
        <lib dir="${srcDirectory}/WEB-INF/lib"/>
        <classes dir="${srcDirectory}/WEB-INF/classes"/>
        <exclude name="common/api/*.js/>
    </war>
    <echo message="Done Creating -> ${workingDirectory}"/>
</target>
```

in my pom.xml i have referenced the folder as

```
<plugin>
  <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
  <executions>
    <execution>
      <id>production</id>
      <phase>package</phase>
      <goals>
        <goal>run</goal>
      </goals>
      <configuration>
        <target>
          <property name="unpackfolder" value="${unpack.folder}"/>
          <property name="webappsrc" value="src/main/webapp"/>
          <property name="srcDirectory" value="${project.basedir}/target"/>
          <property name="workingDirectory" value="${PUBLISH_DIR}/production"/> 
          <ant antfile="${project.basedir}/build.xml" target="production"/>
        </target>
      </configuration>
    </execution>
```

How can i exclude these js files in my war file? for production mode . I plan to exclude these js files and include a minified js file. any pointers

Comment: Is there any particular reason you're not using the `maven-war-plugin`? It would be a lot easier.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Include the `<exclude>` in the `<fileset>`:

```
<fileset dir="${webappsrc}">
    <exclude name="common/api/*.js" />
</fileset>
```

Answer (score 0):

The `exclude` you add directly inside the task not nested into one of the `fileset`s applies to the implicit `fileset` the task forms when you use the `basedir` attribute. Without any `basedir` it doesn't do anything. This may not be mentioned inside the `war` doc, but inside the linked `jar` page.

You have to place the `exclude` inside the `fileset` that pulls in the files you don't want. `lib` and `classes` are `fileset`s with different names (they really only are `zipfileset`s with hard-coded `prefix` attributes).